# How to show the "diff" results in a "more" -like way?

Tags: scroll, screen, diff, output

I am `diff`-ing two files and it scrolls off too much and I cannot see what was the diff at the start of the file. Is there a way for me to do diff and scroll line-by-line by pressing space or something or scrolling page-by-page just like the `more` command does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to pipe the output of `diff` to `more`, like so:

```
diff a.txt b.txt | more
```